# asp.net buttons wont fire their OnClick events

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I think this one is fairly simple to solve as I remeber having this problem before but cant remember what I did about it...

I decided to do away with a particular asp.net page and incorporate some of its controls on another existing page (a few textboxes and 2 buttons), copying and pasting them on and adding the code-behind.

Since doing this none of the buttons on my amended page fire their OnClick events, I tried to add a new one but that doesn't fire either.

The actual code-behind for these buttons are failr simple - save a record, response.redirect, that sort of thing.

Any Ideas?

thanks

button markup

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Save" 
                Width="91px" />
```

code-behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        helper hl = new helper();
        hl.UpdateComplaint(txtCaseNo.Text, Forename.Text, Surname.Text, txtActionProgress.Text,            
 Response.Redirect("Complaint.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the markup of the buttons and the onclick events that they are bound to?

Comment: Most common reasons are covered here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814745 (AutoEventWireup and manually wiring up the event handlers)

Comment: thanks, I'll have a read through

Comment: verify your codefile of your aspx that match with your code behind

Comment: Can you post the page directive of the .aspx? because that is a good one from @Candie

Comment: Thank you JP maybe that solution matching

Comment: page directive looks fine, codebehind matches up and AutoEventWireup = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of things you might try. No guarantees, but maybe a push in the right direction :)

Open up Visual Studio and the ASP.NET page in question. In the Designer, click on the control, and go to the Properties box, and look for the OnClick event. If it's blank, click in the box and select the event handler you wish to attach from the dropdown that is available. If there are no events in the list, just double-click to see if Visual Studio will just create a default event handler for you, then paste the code from the previous onClick handler into that new method.

Hope that helps.

**Edit** Per later comments, suggested that a full copy-and-paste of the codebehind from a different ASP.NET page may have created a partial class declaration that did not match the markup's CodeFile or Inherits directive on the new page, which can cause a variety of odd behavior.

Comment: When I double-click the control it opens the code-behind at the controls click event with the correct code in it - its just doesn't seem to fire

Comment: Did you copy and paste the entire code-behind into the new file? If so, your page-behind may declare a partial class name that differs from that in the "Inherits" declaration on your markup. That can explain all manner of odd behavior.

Comment: I think you're on to something there. Ive undone all changes so Im back to a fully working web app, I'll create the controls instead of copy / paste this time!  Thanks everyone for the comments

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to provide at least some help. Good luck. I'll modify  my answer to incorporate the notion of the last comment I made.

Answer (score 0):

Because you  defined your delegate in code behind specially OnClick event

you must copy this code

```
Button.Click += .....
```

You can associate this delegate in aspx view or in your code behind, for your case you have made in code behind, and you don't copy

Verify your CodeFile of your aspx if you makes copy paste

Comment: In this case, the event delegate is defined in the `*.aspx` markup. Your solution is when you create a button in the code behind or if you bind the event manually in the code behind.

Comment: No it's not my answer, because Theresa have problem of firing, i tell you have two solution : 1 define Onclick on aspx view, or in the Init event of page.

Comment: In her case, if she has made copy paste of view so Onclick is in the copy, so she has defined the OnClick in th code behind -> so if she has copy past just of view, it's not sufficient, because it's possible thta is defined in code behind

Comment: I know what you are saying there, but does that explain why I cant add new buttons successfully? I can add them but again they dont fire...

Comment: Theresa if you add new button, just associate with delegate in view or code behind

Comment: the name of delegate is case sensitive also

Comment: Verify your CodeFile of your aspx

Answer (score 0):

isn't it `OnClick="Button1_Click"` case sensitive? Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the event handler, to see if it fires? And can it be a `Page_Load` issue? That you do things without

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
```